# What characters are Not allowed on the Parquet file name?

Tags: azure, etl, filenames, parquet

I am creating a **parquet file** on the fly.
What special characters are Not allowed for parquet file names?

`~!@#$%^&*()_+/\.,`

?

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Resource Naming Rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/resource-name-rules#microsoftdatafactory), Data Factory Datasets

Can't use:
`<>*#.%&:\\+?/`

Start with alphanumeric.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure - but:

1. In this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/459593/csv-to-parquet-file-conversion.html) it says:

   `Column name cannot contain these character:[,;{}()\\n\\t=]`
2. in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-parquet) it says:

   `White space in column name is not supported for Parquet files.`